# Detect package loss

Tags: ios, swift

For detect internet connection i use simple class:

```
public class Reachability {
    class func isConnectedToNetwork() -> Bool {
        var zeroAddress = sockaddr_in()
        zeroAddress.sin_len = UInt8(sizeofValue(zeroAddress))
        zeroAddress.sin_family = sa_family_t(AF_INET)
        let defaultRouteReachability = withUnsafePointer(&zeroAddress) {
            SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress(nil, UnsafePointer($0))
        }
        var flags = SCNetworkReachabilityFlags()
        if !SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags(defaultRouteReachability!, &flags) {
            return false
        }
        let isReachable = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsReachable)) != 0
        let needsConnection = (flags.rawValue & UInt32(kSCNetworkFlagsConnectionRequired)) != 0
        return (isReachable && !needsConnection)
    }
}
```

Then in my code check:

```
if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == false {
                print("error")
            }
```

But it is not enough to me... Is this possible to detect package loss or something. Because when i simulate this connection:

[image]

I got wrong results. In my app.

Comment: iOS or OSX ? If iOS, you can make use iOS's Network Link Conditioner instead. I think you cannot detect packet loss. But instead, you can detect network connection lost. Libraries like AFNetworking even provide auto retry mechanism.

Comment: is there a solution like: if network.isBad() {}  ?:D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reachability is not affected by the number of packets lost. This could be considered to be a temporary loss of packets as opposed to not having a network connection at all. Reachability is about your 3G, WiFi, or Mac ethernet being turned on, not connection quality. Therefore, those results are not wrong, but intended.